# Why cannot read php://input if a file is sent in Firefox?

Tags: php, firefox, jquery-plugins, file-upload

I'm using the [Valums File Uploader](https://github.com/valums/file-uploader) plugin. This plugin is working on Chrome, but I have a problem with Firefox. I've isolated the problem, but I can't guess what's happening...

The problem is here:

```
function save($path) {
    $input = fopen("php://input", "r");
    $temp = tmpfile();
    $realSize = stream_copy_to_stream($input, $temp);
    fclose($input);

    if ($realSize != $this->getSize()){
        return false;
    }

    $target = fopen($path, "w");
    fseek($temp, 0, SEEK_SET);
    stream_copy_to_stream($temp, $target);
    fclose($target);

    return true;
}
```

This piece of PHP is part of the server, the function that should take the uploaded file and move to a `$path`. The problem is that `$input` contains no data, it's empty. Even if I put this in the first line of my PHP handler file:

```
$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
```

the `$postdata` string is empty. Only in Firefox, not in Chrome. If I go to the client side, Firebug shows that the Firefox is sending the file:

[image]

But if you go to the PHP documentation, it [states that](http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php) "*php://input is not available with enctype="multipart/form-data"*", so I don't know if the problem is `Firefox`, `php://input` or sending a file with `multipart/form-data` (I don't how to send a file without this). What's the problem?

Comment: Why don't you read $_FILES['qqfile'] instead? php://input is supposed to be used with raw post data not separated into POST parameters, so that's why it's not supported.

Comment: Good question. That code is the "official" code from the plugin authors. The question is more about the weird behaivour: it works on Chrome, but not in Firefox. But you are right, I'm changing the code to make it work with $_FILES, but I still have the doubt about why's not working on FF.

Comment: You should create an issue for the project on github, you would have a better feedback on your problem.